# I'm making a c# windows form facebook app

Tags: c#

I finished the design and now making a code that when the user press login the  default name in the home and profile page change to the user name so here is the code and the issue in details :
i set a value to property in an instance of a class but it's value only changed in  Form 1 when i try to use it's value in another form it just returns a null .

(This is form 1)

```
Acc.FirstName = node.SelectSingleNode("FirstName").InnerText;
                Acc.SecondName = node.SelectSingleNode("SecondName").InnerText;
                MessageBox.Show("Welcome "+Acc.FullName);
```

(This is form 3)

```
 public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WindowsFormsApplication15.Form1 f = new 
        WindowsFormsApplication15.Form1();
        linkLabel1.Text =f.Acc.FullName;
        button7.Text = f.Acc.FirstName;

    }
```

Comment: yes, each different form instance will have different state - that is normal and expected; what is it that you want to happen? if you want to store stared state somewhere, then: you'll need to do that

Comment: So what can I do then ?

Comment: Store the state to use need somewhere? To be honest it is pretty unclear what the context is here, but: some kind of state object that you pass between layers is a common fix. Static fields works but is ugly and doesn't scale to multiple consumers

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is that you are creating a new instance of `Form1`. In order to access your account property you'll need to do one of the following:

***Pass The Form***: You can pass `Form1` to `Form3` when you instansiate it:

```
public Form3(Form1 caller) {
    Form1 form1 = caller;
    MessageBox.Show($"{form1.AccountName}");
}
```

***Static Property***: You can make your account property static allowing it to be accessed by other objects so long as it has already been instantiated:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
    public static Account UserAccount { get; set; }
    public Form1() {
        UserAccount = new Account();
    }
}

public Form3() {
    MessageBox.Show($"{Form1.UserAccount.Name}");
}
```